# Issue with compiling a class with numba in a seperate file

Tags: python, numba

I am having trouble using the jitclass decorator with numba to "compile" my python code. And before anyone tells me to read the docs, I have but have no idea where in them to look, so if you are going to tell me that please direct me to a specific point in the numba documentation please :)

An example of what I have right now (if you try and run it, you need to use the -O flag to get it out of debug mode):

```
# class in separate file
print(f"debug state = {__debug__}\n")
if not __debug__:
    from numba import int64, float64    # import types
    from numba import njit
    from numba.experimental import jitclass
    spec = [
        ('init_val', int64),
        ('spacing', float64),
    ]
def blank_dec(*args, **kwargs):
    return args[0]
dec = blank_dec if __debug__ else jitclass(spec)
@dec
class foo:
    def __init__(self, init_val, spacing):
        self.property = init_val
        self.spacing  = spacing
    def foobar(self):
        try:
            # method here, just adding numbers
        except Exception as e:
            if __debug__:
                print(e) # this line appears to give trouble, error below
            else:
                sys.stderr.write(e) # this also causes issues
        

#main file
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foobar = foo(16, 1E-05)
```

This represents the set up I have and reproduces the error that I get. This is the error (file paths redacted with "#######):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>

    foobar = tc.foo(16, 1E-05)

  File "#######/anaconda3/envs/PHYS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/experimental/jitclass/base.py", line 124, in __call__

    return cls._ctor(*bind.args[1:], **bind.kwargs)

  File "#######/anaconda3/envs/PHYS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 482, in _compile_for_args

    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')

  File ""#######/anaconda3/envs/PHYS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 423, in error_rewrite

    raise e.with_traceback(None)

numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)

Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)

Cannot resolve setattr (instance.jitclass.foo#7f433450f1f0<init_val:int64,spacing:float64>).property = int64

File "testclass.py", line 20:
    def __init__(self, init_val, spacing):
        self.property = init_val
        ^

During: typing of set attribute 'property' at "#######/testing/testclass.py (20)

File "testclass.py", line 20:
    def __init__(self, init_val, spacing):
        self.property = init_val
        ^

During: resolving callee type: jitclass.foo#7f433450f1f0<init_val:int64,spacing:float64> During: typing of call at <string> (3)

During: resolving callee type: jitclass.foo#7f433450f1f0<init_val:int64,spacing:float64> During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3: <source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

It appears to be complaining about strings, but I don't understand why. I saw another post that said I needed to use encode to format strings, but this doesn't appear to be my issue.

I have tried taking out the try-except blocks and the initial print statement as well -- as I thought the issue could be related to the print statements, but that does not appear to fix the issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why add all this `if not __debug__:` to your example here? Is it relevant? does the code still fail without it? Please always provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is relevant to project I am working on, though the issue persists without it. I figured I should leave it in just in case there is an issue that I don't see though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as recommended, everything is easier for you and for those who can help you.

For example, you can quickly "distill" the problem into this:

```
spec = [
    ('init_val', nb.int64),
    ('spacing', nb.float64),
    ]

@nb.experimental.jitclass(spec)
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, init_val, spacing):
        self.property = init_val
        self.spacing = spacing

c = Foo(16, 1E-05)
```

While getting the same error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot resolve setattr: (instance.jitclass.Foo#7f29d72ae850<init_val:int64,spacing:float64>).property = int64

File "test_numba.py", line 2569:
        def __init__(self, init_val, spacing):
            self.property = init_val
            ^

During: typing of set attribute 'property' at /home/jotaele/Devel/codetest/tests/test_numba.py (2569)

File "test_numba.py", line 2569:
        def __init__(self, init_val, spacing):
            self.property = init_val
            ^
```

Numba is pointing exactly at the problem: you are not declaring the attribute `property`.

It compiles if you change the specification to:

```
spec = [
    ('property', nb.int64),
    ('spacing', nb.float64),
    ]
```

Even better, you can use type annotations instead of the classic specification:

```
@nb.experimental.jitclass
class Foo:
        
    property: nb.int64
    spacing: nb.float64

    def __init__(self, init_val, spacing):
        self.property = init_val
        self.spacing = spacing
```